# Uniqueness of the predual of a W*-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the following fragments in Takesaki's "Theory of operator algebras" (volume I):

[image: [![enter .com/TJe7o.png]

**Question**: So, we have an *abstract* Banach space $F$ with $A \cong F^*$. In Lemma 3.6, one considers the closed subspace $W:= [\omega A]\subseteq F$. I'm guessing that
$$\omega A := \{\omega(a-): a \in A\}$$ or something like that. However, this looks like a subset of $A^*$, so I'm not sure why it is a subspace of $F$. I thought to look at the canonical embedding $F \hookrightarrow F^{**}\cong A^*$ but this also makes not sense. What does the phrase "$\omega$ is normal" mean in this context? Does it mean that $\omega$ is continuous with the topology coming from the duality $F^* \cong A$ or does it simply mean that $\omega$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous?

Any clarification on the matter will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to think about what Theorem 3.5 tells you!

Firsly, Defintion 2.13 in that chapter tells us what a *normal functional* is.  If $M \subseteq B(H)$ is a von Neumann algebra, then $\omega$ is a normal functional exactly (by definition) when $\omega$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous.

Now Theorem 3.5 tells us that if $M$ is a $W^*$-algebra with (as you say, abstract) predual $F$, then there is a representation $M\rightarrow B(H)$ which is a homeomorphism onto its range, where $M$ is given the $\sigma(M,F)$ topology (that is, the weak$^*$-topology wrt to $F$) and the image is given the $\sigma$-weak topology restricted from $B(H)$.

Once we know this, we simply use that if $\omega$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous, then it's easy to see that $\omega(a-)$ is also $\sigma$-weakly continuous, so by Theorem 3.5, also $\omega(a-)$ is in $F$.